# I can't get my scan results to display in android

Tags: java, android, network-programming

When I run my app on a rooted device the ListView is blank and I am not sure why?

```
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.List;

import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;

import android.widget.Toast;
```

This is my main class:

```
public class Network_List extends AppCompatActivity {

WifiManager wifiM;
WifiScanReciever wifiR;
ListView networklist;
String wifis[];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_network__list);
```

Search box for searching networks (not yet implemented so don't worry about it)

```
    EditText searchNet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.networkEditText);
```

This is the main list to display the network information

```
    networklist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.networkList);
```

Search button for the EditText (This is for future development)

```
    Button networkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
```

scanButton is a button that starts the scan

```
    Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
```

Declares wifiM as wifi manager and gets service

```
    wifiM = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Declares wifiR as WifiScanReciever

```
    wifiR = new WifiScanReciever();
```

Button for starting the scan

```
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            wifiM.startScan();

        }

    });


}

protected void onPause(){
    unregisterReceiver(wifiR);
    super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume(){
    registerReceiver(wifiR, new IntentFilter(wifiM.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}
```

This receives the scan results and puts it an array called wifis. onReceive captures scan results and sets the size of the array wifis.

```
private class WifiScanReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){

        List<ScanResult> wifiSList = wifiM.getScanResults();
        wifis = new String[wifiSList.size()];
        for (int x = 0; x<wifiSList.size(); x++){
            wifis[x] = ((wifiSList.get(x)).toString());
        }
        networklist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wifis));

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Maybe `wifiSList.size()` is 0...

Comment: try to add receiver in manifest and then check

Comment: That worked I will have the code in github soon as an example for others. Thank you for your help!